# synchronisation in tcp chat client

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, synchronization, fork

My application is a multi-user chat room. The server just sends the received message to all clients (echoed to all client including the one from which the received message originated).

For each client, the tasks are:

1. Prompt
2. Take user input
3. Send the message written by the user to the server

At the same time, each client needs to:

1. Receive data (if any) from the server
2. Print to console

To implement above logic I tried using `fork()` as follows:

```
pid = fork();
if(!fork()){
    while(1){
        memset(recvmsg,0,RCVBUFSIZE);
        read(conn_s, recvmsg, RCVBUFSIZE);
        printf("\n>%s",recvmsg);         
    }
}
else{
    while(1){
        printf("\n%d> ", conn_s);
        memset(msg,0,RCVBUFSIZE);
        fgets(msg, RCVBUFSIZE, stdin); 

        strrep(msg,'\n','\0');
        write(conn_s, msg, strlen(msg));

        if( strcmp(msg,"quit") == 0){
            kill(pid, SIGKILL);
            exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, after the first client enters the message echoed back, `msg` is not printed. When the client enters the next message, the last message is printed.

When more than one user is connected, the program behaves inconsistently. It stacks up the received messages and prints them all out in one line.

I tried using `select()` and `poll()`, but the program behaves differently each time.

When the first message entering the echoed mesage is not recieved and from the  next messge it recieved last messages. thus it mess it up when there is more than one user.

Comment: I don't think it's a good approach to do this on top of regular buffered console output. You should look into some library like ncurses to get lower-level console I/O, making it possible to mix that with socket I/O.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might like to use `setbuf(stdout, NULL);` to turn off (line-)buffering for `stdout` and see if things look better.